# Jmeter - Perfmon summary report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

How do we generate summary report of perfmon metrics collector.
I tried looking for references online but could not find relevant information.
We already have summary report in jmeter which gives us avg,min,max,sample etc of a response. However, I want summary of server parameters like memory,CPU, disk I/O.
I can only see below in jmeter and unable to find an option to add summary report of perfmon.

[Perfmon Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csCG2.png)

How can I achieve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the "Filename" in the PerfMon Metrics collector so the metrics will be stored into the file:

[image]

Once your test is done - open the file using i.e. [Aggregate Report listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and you will see these average/min/max/percentiles as for normal samplers:

[image]

You can also generate the table using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. One doubt I have is what are the units for these parameters [aggregate report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tnfh.png)